# How to install a package urdf_tutorial

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, urdf-tutorial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following the tutorials in the wiki step by step. I have encountered urdf tutorial wiki and I am supposed to install the urdf_tutrorial package. I am new to Ubuntu and ROS. Kindly help if possible.
[tutorial link](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Building%20a%20Visual%20Robot%20Model%20with%20URDF%20from%20Scratch)
[package link](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf_tutorial)
[github link](https://github.com/ros/urdf_tutorial)

I tried to check out various questions but couldn't figure it out. I have a catkin workspace.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/339932/how-to-install-a-package-urdf_tutorial/) by [hrushi19](https://answers.ros.org/users/50003/hrushi19/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2019-12-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You basically have two options:

1. Install the debian package (Requires sudo rights): `sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-urdf-tutorial`
2. Clone the source-code directly into your workspace and then rebuild your workspace. See http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/using_a_workspace as a guide to do this.

If you just want to get urdf_tutorial installed, the first option is probably the better and easier choice.

---

Originally posted by [fexner](https://answers.ros.org/users/26760/fexner/) with karma: 221 on 2019-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hrushi19](https://answers.ros.org/users/50003/hrushi19/) on 2019-12-14**:
Thanks, it worked! Is the debian package present in my system or is it installed from the net?
What is a debian package?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-12-14**:
Related: #q320046.